# Getting value from textbox to updata data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox inside a Datalist.I am using the textbox to update data to database.SO far i am able to access the textbox but i get the old value of textbox rather than the updated value.

This is my textbox within datalist.

```
    <asp:DataList ID="profileDl" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="findMYcontrol" >
<ItemTemplate>


<div class="col-md-12 " >
<h2 class="btn btn-primary btn-block profile">Profile</h2>

<asp:Image ID="imgP" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("pp_path")%>' Height="115px" Width="150px" />
</div>

<%-- <div class="row well">--%>
<div class="col-md-12" >
<table>
<tr class="img" >
<td><asp:FileUpload ID="profileUP" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="80px" CssClass="pp" placeholder="okay" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="SelectButton" runat="server" Width="65px"  Height="35px" OnClick="picClick" Class="btn btn-default plus"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus  "></i>&nbsp;Add</asp:LinkButton></td>
</tr>
</table>

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="profile_tb" runat="server">
<asp:Table ID="tbl_profile_edit" runat="server" CssClass="tbl_plbl" >

<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell CssClass="tc_constants" >UserName: </asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="Label7" CssClass="tb" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>'/> </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>

<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell  CssClass="tc_constants" >Real Name:</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="Label8" CssClass="tb" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>'/></asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>

<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell  CssClass="tc_constants">Email:</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="Label9" CssClass="tb" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email")%>'/></asp:TableCell> 
</asp:TableRow>

<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell  CssClass="tc_constants">Address:</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="Label10" CssClass="tb" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("address")%>'/></asp:TableCell> 
</asp:TableRow>  

<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell  CssClass="tc_constants">Sex:</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="Label11" CssClass="tb" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sex")%>'/></asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow> 

<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell  CssClass="tc_constants">Account:</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="Label12" CssClass="tb" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("acType")%>'/></asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>

</asp:Table>

<asp:Button ID="editmyprofile" class="btn btn-default btn-block editbutt" runat="server" OnClick="savemyP" Text="save" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>



</div>
<%--  </div>--%>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

And this is how i am trying to access the textbox value.

```
 protected void gettbId()
{
     string[] st = new string[tbl_pedit.Rows.Count];
       int i= 0;
        foreach (TableRow tr in tbl_pedit.Rows)
        {
            foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Cells)
            {
                foreach (TextBox tb in tc.Controls)
                {

                    st[i] = tb.Text;
                    i++;

                }
            }
        }

        Session["val1"] = st[0].ToString();
        Session["val2"] = st[1].ToString();
        Session["val3"] = st[2].ToString();
        Session["val4"] = st[3].ToString();
        Session["val5"] = st[4].ToString();
        Session["val6"] = st[5].ToString();


}
```

The table `tbl_pedit` is accessed as

```
public void findMYcontrol(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Table tb = (Table)e.Item.FindControl("tbl_profile_edit");
        tbl_pedit = tb;
    }
}
```

But i get the old already existing value in the `session[var]`.How do i get the value i just entered into the textbox.

I am trying to replace the value with the value from textbox.

```
 public void savemyP(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gettbId();
    string st = Session["userid"].ToString();
    string nam = Session["val1"].ToString();
    //string em = Session["val3"].ToString();
    string ad = Session["val4"].ToString();
    string sex = Session["val5"].ToString();
    //string  = Session["val6"].ToString();
    string em = tb_email.Text;
    sq.connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update register set name=@name, address=@address, email =@email, sex=@sex  where reg_id ='" + st + "' ", sq.con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",nam);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address",ad);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",em);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex",sex);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fulname",fn);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sq.con.Dispose();
    sq.con.Close();


}
```

Comment: Are you populating the textboxes with existing data at any point and where in the flow does this happen? You might be repopulating the data prior to postback and then re-saving that

Comment: I am calling the `gettbId` function in the clickevent which is clicked once the textbox is filled with new values.

Comment: you should bind datalist under if(!IsPostBack) Or Not ?

Comment: If i call this function in !page.ispostback,it will take the existing value coz the value is updated in the textbox only after clicking a edit button which causes postback.Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you filling the values of the textboxes inside an

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
    -- Should fill textboxes here
}
```

in your page_load? If not, the values you write are being overwritten every time your page loads, so make sure you fill textbox values only when the request is not a postback.

**EDIT:**

In your Page_Load function, which is called every time your page is loaded, you should do this:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
    Label7.Text = "Your text"; // fill the initial values here, so they are only written once and not overwritten when you click the edit button.
}
```

This way, when you click edit, you will receive your entered values from the postback. If you fill the textboxes inside every page_load, and not only inside if(!IsPostBack) this is what happens:

1. You hit Page_Load and your textbox value is set to "Some text". Your page is displayed to you, textbox1.text is now "Some text"
2. You change text inside the textbox to "Test", and click Edit profile
3. When you click the button, the postback happens, first, page_load is hit, so your textbox value is again set to "Some text"
4. Only after Page_Load, your function is called - and this is why you get the old values again

So - Only fill the textboxes inside the if clause, where you check that it's not a postback. :)

Comment: If i call this function in `!page.ispostback`,it will take the existing value coz the value is updated in the textbox only after clicking a edit button which causes postback

Comment: Probably if(Page.IsPostBack) was meant here. And make sure you doesn't check for the textbox value on PageInit, it gets loaded only before PageLoad event, so probably this is the one you should use.

Comment: The function to get values from the textboxes should be called when it is a postback(that means when you click your Edit button), inside the !Page.IsPostback, you should be filling your textboxes(the initial values that you set - the ones you overwrite later). Like I said, I suspect that you fill your initial values on Page_Load, so every time your page loads, and when your button function is called, your values are again the ones that were filled in originally. I'll edit my original post, to make a clearer answer, give me a minute.